# A better algorithm than Dijkstra's?

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science

> Let `G(V,E)`, a directed and strongly connected graph with weighted edges (can be negative). There're no negative cycles in `G`. Find an algorithm which gets a parameter `k` where `k` is between `2` and `|V|-1` and returns the **weight** of the lightest path from `x` to `y` which uses at most `k` edges.

Now, the solution is creating another graph, with `|V|` layers. The first layer is `x`. Each other layer contains all vertices of `V`. We define edges as follows:

- From the first layer: we connect `x` to some `v` iff there's an edge between them in the original graph (with the same weight)
- From any other layer to the next one: we connect `u` to `v` (different from `u`) iff there's an edge between them in the original graph (With the same weight)
- From `u` of some layer to `u` of the next one, we connect an edge with weight `0`.

Now, we just need to evaluate each layer, inductively (Calculating the shortest path based on the previous one, for each vertex)

The time complexity is `O(|V||E|)`.

Didn't we get an improved algorithm of Dijkstra's? **Since we can now use negative edges** (even though we cannot deal with negative cycles)

Comment: Can you compare your algorithm to [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)? It's slower than Dijkstra, but it can also handle negative length edges.

Comment: Oh actually Dijkstra is better than `O(|V||E|)`.

Comment: In fact, I think your algorithm is strictly worse than Bellman-Ford - it takes up more space (though a smart implementation will discard old layers), and has slower propagation.

Comment: A complete graph is a special case of a generic graph, so yes. But we also know that in a complete graph there are `O(|V|^2) edges`.

Comment: @JanDvorak, Basically you suggested using Bellman-Ford for `k` iterations. Right?

Comment: After the `k` iteration each vertex holds the shortest path from `x` with at most `k` edges.

Comment: If I had to deal with a complete graph and I only cared about the lengths, TBH, I would probably use Floyd-Warshall. Depends on the language tools at hand, too.

Comment: @JanDvorak, please ignore the complete-graph - Bellman-Ford with `k` would accomplish the same result. Right?